# Convert api response in xml to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, api

I need help converting the below API response in xml to pandas dataframe. Can anyone please help?

Here is the XML reponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sunSpecPlantExtract t="2022-08-09T16:54:53Z"><plant id="bb2c469c-9b63-4e64-b95c-6806578889ae" v="1" locale="en-US"><name>Palmyra LLC / Unique Smile</name><activationDate>2016-07-11</activationDate><location><latitude/><longitude/><line1>21 Main St.</line1><city>Milford</city><state>MA</state><postal>01757</postal><timezone>-4:00</timezone></location></plant><sunspecData v="1" periodStart="2022-08-08T06:00:00Z" periodEnd="2022-08-08T23:59:00Z"><d lid="00:90:C2:F7:8C:9C" man="solren" mod="2_20151205" t="2022-08-08T23:40:56Z"><m id="201" sn="F78C9C"><p id="WH">127100</p><p id="WHL">157155200</p><p id="W">9357.4</p></m></d></sunspecData></sunSpecPlantExtract>
```

I have been using the below code to convert but I am not getting the entire data.

```
root = ET.XML(response_data) # element tree
    all_records = []
    for i, child in enumerate(root):
        record = {}
        for subchild in child:
            record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
        all_records.append(record)
    return pd.DataFrame(all_records)
```

I get a partial data like this

```
name    activationDate  location    d
0   Jack Efird #35  2019-07-03  NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: what all columns are you expecting from xml document?

Comment: I am expecting Name, Location, City, State, Postal, periodstart, periodend, W, WH

Answer (score 0):

assuming that everytime your API response will generate static xml fields.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4


records = {}

with open("a.xml", "rb") as xml_file:
    infile = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_file, features="xml")

    records["name"] = infile.find("name").text
    records["activationdate"] = infile.find("activationDate").text
    records["location"] = (
        infile.find("line1").text
        + " "
        + infile.find("city").text
        + " "
        + infile.find("state").text
    )
    records["tz"] = infile.find("timezone").text


df = pd.DataFrame(records, index=[k for k in records.keys()])

print(df)
```